# Python mysqldb on Mac OSX 10.6 not working

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos

I am using Python 2.7 and trying to get a Django project running on a MySQL backend.

I have downloaded mysqldb and followed the guide here:http://cd34.com/blog/programming/python/mysql-python-and-snow-leopard/

Yet when I go to run the django project the following traceback occurs:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/andyarmstrong/Documents/workspace/BroadbandMapper/src/BroadbandMapper/manage.py", line 11, in 
>     execute_manager(settings)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
>     utility.execute()
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
>     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
>     self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 209, in execute
>     translation.activate('en-us')
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 66, in activate
>     return real_activate(language)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 55, in _curried
>     return _curried_func(*(args+moreargs), **dict(kwargs, **morekwargs))
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 36, in delayed_loader
>     return getattr(trans, real_name)(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 193, in activate
>     _active[currentThread()] = translation(language)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 176, in translation
>     default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
>     app = import_module(appname)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
>     __import__(name)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 1, in 
>     from django.contrib.admin.helpers import ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py", line 1, in 
>     from django import forms
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/__init__.py", line 17, in 
>     from models import *
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 6, in 
>     from django.db import connections
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 77, in 
>     connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
>     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 33, in load_backend
>     return import_module('.base', backend_name)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
>     __import__(name)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 14, in 
>     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/andyarmstrong/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib
>   Referenced from: /Users/andyarmstrong/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
>   Reason: image not found
> ```

I have tried the following also:http://whereofwecannotspeak.wordpress.com/2007/11/02/mysqldb-python-module-quirk-in-os-x/
adding a link between the mysql lib directory and somewhere else...

Help!

Comment: SO doesn't use BBCode, it uses markdown. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more. Also, output should be marked with `<quote>`, `<blockquote>` or [(someday) `<samp>`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user/72326#72326) and `<pre>` (see edited source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually managed to solve the problem by Installing python 2.7 with Mac Ports and installing mysqldb using Mac Ports - was pretty simple after that.

Comment: what was the name of the package for 2.7 and mysqldb you used with mac ports?

Comment: holy smokes - ive tried everything and this actually worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you needed to add the MySQL client libraries to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.